# Swift: How can i put cells together and adjust the cell width of a TableView depending on the amount of text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am familiar with `TableView/CollectionsView` and `TableViewCells/CollectionsViewCells` and loading data onto them.

I am however facing a challenge, I have an `array` of sentences and i'm hoping to achieve the design below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPnFT.jpg

Think of it as though you are reading a book and each cell contains a sentence. So you would want a sentence to start after a full stop and not in a new line. Image should explain what i'm trying to achieve. In this case a cell should start when one cells ends.

So i'm not sure on how to approach this challenge. If you could please share your suggestions.

I have successfully loaded the data into the `tableview` and `collectionview` and i have tried adjusting the size of the cells. However, the cells are not wrapping.

Comment: Maybe this library can help?
Ref: https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with UICollectionView using custom Flow layout.
Here [it](https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout/blob/master/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout/Classes/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout.swift) is.